# Force CMake to use C++ compiler for C files with Visual Studio

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, cmake

I have generated .h and .c files which must be compiled as C++ files with Visual Studio.
I heard I could do something like `set_source_files_properties( ${SOURCES} PROPERTIES LANGUAGE "CXX" )`. In parallel, I have read that I should not do that as it should used only in exotic situations.

**So, what is the best way to force CMake to generate VS projects which compiles C files as C++ files?**

PS: renaming the generated files is not an option.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have been using the individual properties (most likely you can also set directory properties - but this is not as fine grained) without any problems. Not for setting the language though (but why should it be any different?):

```
SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES( file1.c PROPERTIES LANGUAGE CXX )
```

This works under Linux and Windows and doesn't seem to pose any problems. What have you heard that makes you hesitate?

Comment: Edited - I've been using `SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES` for specific compile flags and definitions and it worked as a charm.

Comment: What is the modern method to do so?

Comment: @Royi I think that it didn't changed too much in modern CMake. You probably can try to change target property, but thing for files will likely stay the same.

Comment: Clang prints a **deprecated** message: `clang: warning: treating 'c-header' input as 'c++-header' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]`

Comment: Is it possible to force it from the command line and not from the _CMakeLists.txt_ files?