# CMake Project-level CXX override

Tags: cmake

Is it possible to treat all .c files as CXX at a project level in CMake? I know `set_source_files_properties(... PROPERTIES LANGUAGE CXX)` can do this but I'd prefer to use fewer lines if possible. There's no single variable in my `CMakeLists.txt` that has all source files.

I don't believe [Tell CMake to use C++ compiler for C files coming from CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37931068/tell-cmake-to-use-c-compiler-for-c-files-coming-from-cmake) helps here - that's about errors related to interpreting the file types. I have no issue with overriding the LANGUAGE property, but as stated, I'd prefer not to apply it to all the various source files. I know CMake has a lot of knobs. I was hoping this would be one somewhere.